# Microsoft Asp.Net Identity 2.0 - Entity Framework vs. Custom Provider

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am writing a new web site and am looking at Asp.Net Identity 2.0.  Out of the box, it uses Entity Framework for all of its data access.  For the rest of the site, we were creating middleware web services for data access.  Our original plan for security sake was that the web servers would talk to middleware and middleware would talk to the database via Entity Framework.  We had planned on blocking via firewall database access from the web server.

I see that I can create a custom provider for Identity 2.0 and it in turn could use middleware for it's data access.

Here are my questions:

1. Is it more secure to not allow the web servers to have direct database access?
2. If it is more secure, why would Microsoft not build it that way out of the box
3. If you were starting from scratch like we are, would you recommend using entity framework or writing a custom provider that goes through our middleware layer?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just create a "security" web service and do the ASP.Net Identity stuff in there, calling it from your website? 1. Something somewhere needs access to the database eventually.  2. Microsoft provides the libraries.  How you implement them is another thing. 3. I would use ASP.NET Identity as is, and then if needed move other business logic / data access into your web services where needed.

Comment: yes - I guess I am looking for a best practice from a security perspective...

Answer (score 0):

1.) It can be secure. I don't see it as a security issue but coupling issue. What if you want to upgrade or change from Entity Framework in the future? What if you want to change from Identity 2.0? What if you want to upgrade one but you can't because the other doesn't support it yet.

2.) Microsoft wanted to promote it products first and foremost. For simplicity sake if your ok with Entity Framework and Identity 2.0 and don't mind how coupled they are it could be perfectly fine solution.

3.) How much time/effort can you afford to spend on the custom provider? It might not be worth the effort to create your own provider.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.NET Identity out-of-the-box is actually Asp.Net Identity on Entity Framework. It generates a database, connection string, the model files, the controllers and a context class for you, which you can redirect to your own database for it to generate the Identity tables within. Everything is very secure, and they've taken care of a lot of the authentication/password hashing for you. I wouldn't say it is worth it to create your own provider, but you can also create your own provider within Identity if you want. Identity 2.0 is great. Very easy to add custom table properties, etc.